# Ajax Post URL with button id, Django Server

Tags: ajax, django

I'm trying to delete an element in a list by clicking a button, each button got the pk of the element as id

```
$('.delete').on('click', function (event) {
var evaluacion_id = this.id;
$.confirm({
    title: 'Desea Eliminar Evaluacion?',
    content: 'De ser asi no podra Recuperar estos datos',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function (evaluacion_id) {
            var url = "{% url 'delete-evaluacion' evaluacion_id %}"
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: url,
                success: function(){
                    location.href="{% url 'evaluaciones-psicologo' informe.proceso.pk %}"
                }
            }); 
        },
        cancel: function () {
            $.alert('Continue Evaluando');
        },

    }
})
```

});

if i do `$.alert("Delete "+evaluacion_id);` instead of the ajax function everything its ok and it shows me the correct id

But if I call it with ajax function, throws me this

```
Reverse for 'delete-evaluacion' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['INTRANET\\/delete-evaluacion/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']
```

And my urls.py

```
url(r'^procesos/EvaluacionesPsicologo/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.evaluaciones_psicologo,name='evaluaciones-psicologo'),
url(r'^procesos/EvaluacionePsicologo/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.evaluacion_psicologo,name='evaluacion-psicologo'),
url(r'^delete-evaluacion/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.EliminarEvaluacion, name='delete-evaluacion'),
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the template tag `{% url 'delete-evaluacion' evaluacion_id %}` is evaluated when the template is rendered, not when the JavaScript is run. Django doesn't know the variable `evaluacion_id`, so it tries to reverse the URL with an empty string, which doesn't match the URL pattern.

The proper way to do this would be to get the URL pattern and transform it into the template URL format, but that would require diving deep into the internals of Django's URL resolving and is probably not worth the hassle. There is a library that does that for you: [Django JS Reverse](https://github.com/ierror/django-js-reverse)

A more pragmatic approach would be to reverse the URL with a dummy ID, which you then replace in JavaScript.

```
$('.delete').on('click', function (event) {
var evaluacion_id = this.id;
$.confirm({
    title: 'Desea Eliminar Evaluacion?',
    content: 'De ser asi no podra Recuperar estos datos',
    buttons: {
        confirm: function (evaluacion_id) {
            var url = "{% url 'delete-evaluacion' 9999 %}".replace('9999', evaluacion_id);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: url,
                success: function(){
                    location.href="{% url 'evaluaciones-psicologo' informe.proceso.pk %}"
                }
            }); 
        },
        cancel: function () {
            $.alert('Continue Evaluando');
        },

    }
})
```

Comment: Just did the change using the dummy ID, got this `[21/Jun/2018 03:24:53] "POST /INTRANET/delete-evaluacion/9999 HTTP/1.1" 500 17963`, it's not doing the replace

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. `replace` does not modify the string, it returns a new one. I've edited the code and will now get some coffee :)

Comment: On a side note, my policy is that invalid user input (like an invalid URL) should never result in a 500 server error. I suggest catching the exception and returning a 404